# I need to add the int variables in my code together, any ideas how?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from package where pkgid = '" + txtpkgid.Text + "' ", con);
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int HC = Convert.ToInt32(dr["HC"]);
        int KC = Convert.ToInt32(dr["KC"]);
        int DC = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DC"]);
        int DONR = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DONR"]);
        int VNPR = Convert.ToInt32(dr["VNPR"]);

    }
    con.Close();


    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from vehicle where RegistrationNo = '" + txtcarid.Text + "' ", con);
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int VDP = Convert.ToInt32(dr["VDP"]);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

**How to add the above?**

sorry, I'm a beginner so this probably looks really stupid to ask, any help on how to add them together is much appreciated.

basically I want to get
Result = HC+KC+DC+DONR+VNPR+VDP
and display the Result in a label.

The problem is I don't know how to bring Value of VDP out.

Comment: probably you're looking for ExecuteScalar(), and not Reader. So, you can do this `SELECT HC+KC+DC+DONR+VNPR+VDP  FROM vehicle ...etc`

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
    long result = 0;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["HC"]);
        result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["KC"]);
        result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["DC"]);
        result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["DONR"]);
        result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["VNPR"]);

    }
    con.Close();
```

Note that you should properly dispose of the command and reader objects.
And as other commenter noted, you can compute this sum on SQL side, so you don't have to iterate over the resultset.
If you keep using the client-side iterator, also remember to add proper NULL handling, in case if dr[...] can return a `null` or `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your int in the outer scope, actualy they are only accesible in those while block.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from package where pkgid = '" + txtpkgid.Text + "' ", con);
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //We declare variables here so we can access them
        int HC = 0;
        int KC = 0;
        int DC = 0;
        int DONR = 0;
        int VNPR = 0;
        int VDP = 0;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            int HC = Convert.ToInt32(dr["HC"]);
            int KC = Convert.ToInt32(dr["KC"]);
            int DC = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DC"]);
            int DONR = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DONR"]);
            int VNPR = Convert.ToInt32(dr["VNPR"]);
        }
        con.Close();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from vehicle where RegistrationNo = '" + txtcarid.Text + "' ", con);
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            int VDP = Convert.ToInt32(dr["VDP"]);
        }

        con.Close();

        int result = HC + KC + DC + DONR + VNPR VDP;

        //We pass the total to the label
        Yourlabel.Text = result;
    }
```

Comment: Note : you can use Roman Polunin solution. It's a cleaner  one especialy if you dont need to reuse those variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it like this, assuming you are parsing the `SqlConnection con` and also that your `RegistrationNo` does not have the same columns as `pkgid`  table.

```
public int AddSqlResults(SqlConnection con)
{
    int result = 0;
    var queries = new [] { "select * from package where pkgid = '" + txtpkgid.Text + "'", 
                           "select * from vehicle where RegistrationNo = '" + txtcarid.Text + "'" };
    foreach (var query in queries)
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["HC"]);
                    result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["KC"]);
                    result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["DC"]);
                    result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["DONR"]);
                    result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["VNPR"]);
                    result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["VDP"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Call the function like so...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = AddSqlResults(con).ToString();
}
```